# I got an error when I am connecting firebase to my react app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, email, typeerror

`firebase config.js`:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore/lite';

import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "###",
    authDomain: "####",
    projectId: "###",
    storageBucket: "####",
    messagingSenderId: "###",
    appId: "1:834942070276:web:###",
    measurementId: "#"
  };
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  const db = getFirestore(app);

  export default { db,auth,createUserWithEmailAndPassword} ;
```

`signup.js`

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';

import Logo from '../../olx-logo.png';
import './Signup.css';
import FirebaseContext from '../../storage/FirebaseContext';

export default function Signup() {
  const [name,setName]=useState('')
  const [email,setEmail]=useState('')
  const [password,setPassword]=useState('')
  const [phone,setPhone]=useState('')
  const firebase=useContext(FirebaseContext)
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // console.log(firebase);
  if (!firebase) {
    console.error('Firebase not initialized');
    return;
  }

  firebase.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      console.log('User signed up:', userCredential);
      const user = userCredential.user;
      
      // Update user profile
      // user.updateProfile({
      //   displayName: name
      // })
      //   .then(() => {
      //     console.log('User profile updated successfully');
      //   })
      //   .catch((profileError) => {
      //     console.error('Error updating user profile:', profileError);
      //   });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      console.error('Error creating user:', errorCode, errorMessage);
    });
} 

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="signupParentDiv">
        <img width="200px" height="200px" src={Logo}></img>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="fname">Username</label>
          <br />
          <input
            className="input"
            type="text"
            id="fname"
            name="name"
            defaultValue="John"  value={name}
            onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.target.value)}}
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="fname">Email</label>
          <br />
          <input
            className="input"
            type="email"
            id="fname"
            name="email"  value={email}
            defaultValue="John" onChange={(e)=>{setEmail(e.target.value)}}
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="lname">Phone</label>
          <br />
          <input
            className="input"
            type="number"
            id="lname"
            name="phone"  value={phone}
            defaultValue="Doe" onChange={(e)=>{setPhone(e.target.value)}}
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="lname">Password</label>
          <br />
          <input
            className="input"
            type="password"
            id="lname"
            name="password"  value={password}
            defaultValue="Doe" onChange={(e)=>{setPassword(e.target.value)}}
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          <button>Signup</button>
        </form>
        <a>Login</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error:  Signup.js:40 Error creating user: undefined authInternal._getRecaptchaConfig is not a function

In the Signup component, I'm using Firebase for user authentication. I encountered an issue related to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. I've checked the Firebase setup, and the imports seem correct. However, I keep getting an error:

> TypeError: firebase.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function

Could you help me spot any potential issues or suggest areas to investigate further in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `auth` instance in the call to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.

You can try this:

```
firebase.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
    //code does something

}
```